# Print PDF client side using javascript/jquery/java

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, pdf

I am trying to print the pdf using following code:

```
 $('#print').click(function() {

     var data = $(this).data('loc-subject');

     alert(data);
     var myWindow=window.open(data,'','width=500,height=500');

     var doc = myWindow.document;
     myWindow.document.writeln('<embed type="application/pdf" src="'+data+'" id="pdfDocument" width="100%" height="100%" />');
     myWindow.document.writeln('<script type="text/javascript">');
     myWindow.document.writeln('function load()');
     myWindow.document.writeln('{');
     myWindow.document.writeln('window.focus();');

     doc.writeln('setTimeout(function() {window.print();}, 3000);');

     myWindow.document.writeln('}');
     myWindow.document.writeln('</scr'+'ipt>');
     myWindow.document.writeln("<body onload=load()>");
     myWindow.document.writeln("</body>");

    myWindow.document.close();
```

});

But It has several flaws:

1. Not properly working in IE.
2. In Firefox its working fine but only printing the first page of pdf.
3. Using Iframe also giving the same result.

The PDF file is present server side on crx and I just want to print the pdf to the client machine on a link click.

If anybody has working code or guidance on this it would really help me here.

Thanks.

Comment: Never done this but if it was me I would try to load the pdf url into an iframe and use a load event on the iframe to trigger printing of the iframe window. Can set the iframe position to be off screen so user doesn't even see it

Comment: Using iframe gives the error that print is not allowed in the browser console.If possible can you please give me any sample working code because I tried using iframe and it gave me error that print operation not permitted.

Comment: That probably does make sense due to iframe security policies. Printing without user interaction is probably the main problem also